# how to create a matrix of tuples that is initialize with zeroes

Tags: python, image, numpy, matrix

I am creating a picture and I use numpy. 
I tried something like that but got an error
    data = np.zeros((pic.size[0], pic.size[1],2),dtype= [[(0,0,0)],])
I am trying to make it look like

```
[[(0,0,0),(0,0,0),(0,0,0)],[(0,0,0),(0,0,0)]]
```

how can i do it? i need to put this data in the putdata() method
which get matrix of tuples.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a [`NumPy array of zeros`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/reference/generated/numpy.zeros.html#numpy.zeros), split it at `3rd index` and then [`map`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html?highlight=map#map) them to tuple with a loop comrehension, like so -

```
split_zeros = np.split(np.zeros((5,3),dtype=int),[3],axis=0)
out = [map(tuple,item) for item in split_zeros]
```

Sample run -

```
In [166]: split_zeros = np.split(np.zeros((5,3),dtype=int),[3],axis=0)

In [167]: [map(tuple,item) for item in split_zeros]
Out[167]: [[(0, 0, 0), (0, 0, 0), (0, 0, 0)], [(0, 0, 0), (0, 0, 0)]]
```

Answer (score 3):

When I test your first line I get an error

```
In [156]: data=np.zeros((3,4,2),dtype= [[(0,0,0)],])
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-156-9f6f75b73353> in <module>()
----> 1 data=np.zeros((3,4,2),dtype= [[(0,0,0)],])

TypeError: data type not understood
```

Does that expression run for you or not?  You make it sound like it does.  If it doesn't you should be clear about the error.

But what exactly do you mean by a matrix of tuples? Just something that displays

```
[[(0,0,0),(0,0,0),(0,0,0)],[(0,0,0),(0,0,0)]]
```

You mention a `putdata` method.  What package are you talking about? Not `numpy`.

I can create a structure array that displays like this

```
In [158]: np.zeros((2,2),dtype='i,i,i')
Out[158]: 
array([[(0, 0, 0), (0, 0, 0)],
       [(0, 0, 0), (0, 0, 0)]], 
      dtype=[('f0', '<i4'), ('f1', '<i4'), ('f2', '<i4')])


In [159]: print(np.zeros((2,2),dtype='i,i,i'))
[[(0, 0, 0) (0, 0, 0)]
 [(0, 0, 0) (0, 0, 0)]]
```

Technically this doesn't contain tuples, though it uses the tuple syntax.  Converting it to a list may be better.

```
In [160]: np.zeros((2,2),dtype='i,i,i').tolist()
Out[160]: [[(0, 0, 0), (0, 0, 0)], [(0, 0, 0), (0, 0, 0)]]
```

This last result is a nested list - list of lists of tuples.

But is really important that the inner elements be tuples?

```
In [179]: np.zeros((2,2,3),int)
Out[179]: 
array([[[0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0]],

       [[0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0]]])

In [180]: np.zeros((2,2,3),int).tolist()
Out[180]: [[[0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0]], [[0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0]]]
```

Often in Python lists and tuples are interchangeable.

We need to know more about that `putdata` method.

===============

I'm guessing from a search that `putdata` is a `PIL` method.

In that case, this works:

```
In [240]: from PIL import Image

In [241]: im=Image.new('RGB',(10,10))    
In [243]: im.putdata(np.ones((100,),dtype='i,i,i').tolist())
```

`im.putdata(np.ones((10,10),dtype='i,i,i').tolist())` doesn't work; it looks like the data has to be a flat list

```
[(0,0,0),(0,1,0), etc]
```

`im.putdata([(0,1,0)]*100)` also works, since it is just a simple list replication of the tuple.

Comment: thanks! my main problem was that i should have used a flat list in the putdata method.